# Create 'x' number of rows of checkboxes in Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, checkbox, awt

```
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.TextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Status extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    private TextField tf1 = new TextField();
    private Button btn = new Button("Deploy");
    JPanel grid;
    public Status()
    {
        new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2));
        tf1.setSize(new Dimension(40,40));
        btn.setSize(new Dimension(30,30));

        grid.add(tf1);
        grid.add(btn);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        if(ae.getSource() == btn)
        {
            int x = Integer.parseInt(tf1.getText());
            //Checkbox [][] a = {new Checkbox("1"};
            for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
            {
                JCheckBox jc = new JCheckBox(""+i); 
                grid.add(jc);
            }

        }

    }

}
```

This is my code. I want to create 'x' number of rows of Checkboxes, where 'x' is the numeric value input by the user through a TextField. Each row of the checkbox (no matter what the value), should contain 8 Checkboxes each. Please help!

Comment: What does your program output at the moment?

Comment: @RyanJ A NullPointer Exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the code to do what you want it to do. 
Please follow it using the many comments I added :

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.TextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Status extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    private TextField tf1 = new TextField();
    private Button btn = new Button("Deploy");
    private JPanel grid;
    private static final int COLUMNS = 8;

    public Status()
    {
        //you forgot to assign it to grid
        grid = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, COLUMNS)); //0 means any number of rows
        tf1.setColumns(5);// set sixe by number of columns
        //btn.setSize(new Dimension(30,30));
        //there is no need to set size to the btn, but you must add the
        //action listener to it
        btn.addActionListener(this);

        //create a panel to hold controls
        JPanel controls = new JPanel(); //uses FlowLayout by default
        //add controls to it
        controls.add(new JLabel("Number of checkboxes to add "));
        controls.add(tf1);     controls.add(btn);

        //create a panel to hold grid and controls
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5,5));
        //add controls at its top
        mainPanel.add(controls, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        //add grid to its center
        mainPanel.add(grid, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        //add mainPanel to frame
        add(mainPanel);

        //do jframe setting
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

        if(ae.getSource() == btn)
        {
            //surround with try - catch to protect from wrong input
            int numberOfRows = Integer.parseInt(tf1.getText());
            for (int row = 0; row < numberOfRows; row++)
            {
                for(int col = 0; col< COLUMNS ; col++) {
                    JCheckBox jc = new JCheckBox(""+row+""+col);
                    grid.add(jc);
                }
            }
        }
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()-> new Status());
    }
}
```

Don't hesitate to ask for clarifications as needed.

Comment: Uh, thanks for the quick reply! But I didn't quite understand what you implemented in main() i.e. SwingUtilities. What does it do?

Comment: It runs `new Status()` on [The Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). You can ignore it if you like (replace it with `new Status();`)  and come back to it when you are ready.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the explanation. But I want the program to generate 'x' rows of Checkboxes. Each row has 8 Checkboxes in it. Your improvised code generates 'x' no. of checkboxes. I want 'x' no. of rows of checkboxes.

Comment: The purpose of this site is not to write code for you. The purpose is to help you understand what needs to be done. I am sorry if the posted code did not help with it

Comment: Don't be sorry. Your code DID help me. Thanks again and sorry if it felt like I was asking you to write code for me.